# How to change datatype whithout dropping dependencies

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to change the precision of a `decimal` column without dropping and recreating the dependencies of it?

I tried the following:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
    ALTER COLUMN MyColumn DECIMAL(10, 3) NULL

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"
```

When I execute this query I get the error messages:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   The object 'MyView' is dependent on column 'MyColumn'.
>
> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   The index 'MyIndex' is dependent on column 'MyColumn'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 8
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN MyColumn failed because one or more objects access this column.

Is it possible to change it without dropping and recreating the dependencies?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258380/preserve-sql-indexes-while-altering-column-datatype

Comment: No, it is **not** possible to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found a way to do this. Although it probably isn't the best solution, it worked for us so if anyone has the same problem, try the following:

In SQL Server Management Studio go to `Tools -> Options -> Designer` and uncheck the box of **"Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"**

Next rightclick the table you want to modify the column datatypes and click on **"Design"**.

In the designer, edit the column datatype to the one you need.

Finally, right-click and choose **"Generate Change Script"**.

---

What it does is the following:

- Drop the constraints on the table
- Create a temp table with the new datatype of the column
- Readd constraints to the **temp table**
- Set the `IDENTITY_INSERT` on the temp table to `ON`
- Copy all data from the old table to the new temp table
- Set the `IDENTITY_INSERT` on the temp table to `OFF`
- Drop the old table
- Rename the temp table to the name of the old table
- Readd the primary key constraint
- Recreate the indexes
- Readd the foreign key constraints

Additionally you have to refresh all depending views.
You can generate the statements with this script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'EXEC sp_refreshview ''' + s.name + '.' + so.name + '''' AS 'dbo.TABLENAME'
FROM sys.objects AS so 
INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed 
    ON so.object_id = sed.referencing_id 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON so.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE so.type = 'V' AND sed.referenced_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TABLENAME');
```

- Check the box of "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation" in `Tools -> Options -> Designer`

> Please be careful about this! See if it really does what you are looking for. Keep in mind that this drops the old table. **Test this in a development environment!**

Comment: Question: Why dropping the table and recreating it with all the constraints is better than dropping the constraint, changing the column and recreating the constraint?

Comment: Yeah good question, I've only described the script that the Sql Server Management Studio generates. Since we had to do it on a lot of tables, we needed a way to script it. But you're probably right, it will likely work like this as well