# How to remove, ALTER, then recreate any database objects that access a column using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a giant old legacy SQL Server database. I am trying to change every `datetime` to `datetime2`, but the simple approach (a looping TSQL script using a cursor) hits many snags like this:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The index 'IX_Table_ColId_ModifiedOn' is dependent on column 'ModifiedOn'
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ModifiedOn failed because one or more objects access this column.

Besides indices, there are computed columns, default constraints, and other things that use these columns, blocking the ALTER.

Avoiding downtime is not an issue for us. Is there a magic TSQL script or technique that can just find things connected to a column/table, remove them temporarily, allow the ALTER, then recreate them?

Related questions:

- [Preserve SQL Indexes While Altering Column Datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258380/preserve-sql-indexes-while-altering-column-datatype)

Comment: if it's not an issue, then you can drop all constraints and indexes, do your changes, and readd them. Is this not an option?

Comment: The linked post is **exactly** though not completely what you need to do. Just get on with it since there is no magic command to do this. And include views since schema-binding will also prevent such changes.

Comment: @scsimon There's like 1000 tables and dozens of random ways the datetime columns get used.  It will take ages to figure out manually.

Comment: @SMor: The linked question is similar, but has no good, complete answer.  I'm pretty sure it's theoretically possible to build this script, it will just take forever and have many edge cases.  It must have been built by someone, somewhere, and I'm trying to find it so I don't have to do it myself.

Comment: well you don't have to do that manually. I'd drop ALL the constraints in the DB via a cursor after scripting them out throught he gui

Answer (score 0):

What I think you could try is to find all the tables that have columns with `DATETIME` datatype, as well as if they have any indexes. Please consider the following:

```
create table #TempTable (
TableName VARCHAR(MAX),
ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX),
IndexName VARCHAR(MAX)
)

;WITH CTE1(TableName, ColumnName) AS
(
    SELECT
        so.name table_name
       ,sc.name column_name
    from sysobjects so
    inner join syscolumns sc on (so.id = sc.id)
    inner join systypes st on (st.type = sc.type)
    where so.type = 'U'
    and st.name IN ('DATETIME')
),
CTE2(TABLEName, ColumnName, IndexName) AS
(
           SELECT cte1.TableName, c.name, i.name
    FROM    sys.index_columns AS ic
            INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
                ON ic.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
                AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
            INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
                ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
                AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
            INNER JOIN cte1 AS cte1 ON cte1.columnName = c.name


)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM CTE2

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

Then you could do some dynamic SQL to do the following:

```
--Dynamic SQL populate values

    BEGIN
        -- drop index
        -- alter column 
        -- delete row from temp table
        -- recreate index
        -- process next row

    END
```

There is probably a better way to do the last part once you got the data, I will let you do it. Hope this helps.